# How to best implement server and client in python?

Tags: python, server, client, ipc, shared-memory

I have a large file that needs to be loaded into memory, then some operations can be done based on the user input. But I don't want to load the file into memory again and again whenever there is a user input.

A solution might be to load the data file by a process as the "server", and have another client process to query the server on behalf of the client.

I am wondering what the best client-server implementation for this is. I know that I could implement an HTTP server, but querying it needs to follow the HTTP protocol which has too much overhead (For my specific, the client only needs to send a string to the server, so all the HTTP headers are not needed.) A lighter solution is preferred. Also, both the client and the server are supposed to run in the same machine, so using memory is faster than using networking for sharing the information between the client and the server?

Actually, the server could just load the data into the memory as some python objects, if there is a way to access these python objects from the client, it should be also fine.

Could anybody offer some advice on the best solution to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What sort of data is the file?

Comment: It doesn't matter. As the solution that I look for should be independent of the data. For example, if the data is just a table, I could just use sqlite3. That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, it does slightly matter so we can try and figure out a solution that's as optimal as possible for your use case. How do you need to access the data in the client, for instance? A slice of a binary array? All at once? Etc.

Comment: How about using `mmap`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html

Comment: The strings will not be sent all at once. Each time just send a string. The returned result is a dictionary or list, which can be large. So I don't want the server to compute the results once and send it back because this will result in an extra copy. I'd think directly access the objects in the server from the client might be better.

Comment: If there is just one user of this app, you could build a simple UI (using tkinter may be) if you want something fancy or just have it as command line (using input() in some sort of loop). And as far as the data, I hope it fits in the memory, that way you could cache it in some collection and then do whatever operations based on user input

Comment: @DroidX86 So the server can just load the file and put it in the memory by mmap, how to make sure the server process persists so that the info in the memory is not released? Or is it possible to make the data persist in memory even when the process load the data finish?

Comment: @ranjith I am not looking for GUI. The access must be by a program.

Comment: You probably want to use an actual database for something like. What you're describing & the problems you're trying to solve have already been solved by countless databases systems.

Comment: @DroidX86 There is no such database matching my needs.

Comment: And your requirements are...?

Comment: Again, query with a string and return an object.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so based on the comments, the data is keyed by string and values are lists or dictionaries, and the client requests an object by string.

Unfortunately there's no safe, sane way to directly access that sort of data cross-process without some intermediate serialization/deserialization step. An obvious choice, safety concerns aside, is `pickle`ing them. `msgpack` is reasonable too.

As for the protocol, if tried-and-tested HTTP is too slow for you, for a simple request-response cycle like this, maybe just have the client send the key to retrieve, followed by a null character or a newline or whatnot, and the server directly reply with the serialized object, and then close the connection.

You might also want to consider simply storing the serialized data in a database, be it SQLite or something else.

---

*EDIT:* I decided to experiment a little. Here's a small, pretty naive `asyncio` + `msgpack` based server + client that does the trick:

## server.py

```py
import asyncio
import random
import msgpack
import time
from functools import lru_cache


def generate_dict(depth=6, min_keys=1, max_keys=10):
    d = {}
    for x in range(random.randint(min_keys, max_keys)):
        d[x] = (
            generate_dict(
                depth=depth - 1, min_keys=min_keys, max_keys=max_keys
            )
            if depth
            else "foo" * (x + 1)
        )
    return d


DATA = {f"{x}": generate_dict() for x in range(10)}


@lru_cache(maxsize=64)
def get_encoded_data(key):
    # TODO: this does not clear the cache upon DATA being mutated
    return msgpack.packb(DATA.get(key))


async def handle_message(reader, writer):
    t0 = time.time()
    data = await reader.read(256)
    key = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info("peername")
    print(f"Sending key {key!r} to {addr!r}...", end="")
    value = get_encoded_data(key)
    print(f"{len(value)} bytes...", end="")
    writer.write(value)
    await writer.drain()
    writer.close()
    t1 = time.time()
    print(f"{t1 - t0} seconds.")


async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_message, "127.0.0.1", 8888)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f"Serving on {addr}")

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


asyncio.run(main())
```

## client.py

```py
import socket
import msgpack
import time


def get_key(key):
    t0 = time.time()
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8888))
    s.sendall(str(key).encode())
    buf = []
    while True:
        chunk = s.recv(65535)
        if not chunk:
            break
        buf.append(chunk)
    val = msgpack.unpackb(b"".join(buf))
    t1 = time.time()
    print(key, (t1 - t0))
    return val


t0 = time.time()
n = 0
for i in range(10):
    for x in range(10):
        assert get_key(x)
        n += 1
t1 = time.time()
print("total", (t1 - t0), "/", n, ":", (t1 - t0) / n)
```

On my Mac,

- it takes about 0.02814 seconds per message on the receiving end, for a single-consumer throughput of 35 requests per second.
- it takes about 0.00241 seconds per message on the serving end, for a throughput of 413 requests per second.

(And as you can see from how the `DATA` is generated, the payloads can be quite large.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: SQLite is definitely not the solution, as it involves the disk. Depending on the disks the performance can be slow. Everything must be in memory. There will be computational on the data, it is more efficient to make the computation and send the result (which is small). If directly get the data and then do the computation in the client, the data get by client will be large. So any database solution is not appropriate for my problem.

Comment: The connection approach is also a concern. I think that in C there is a way to make a piece of data persistent in memory. (`ipcs` and `ipcrm` can show info of shared memory and remove a piece of shared memory). Is there a way to make a python object persistent in memory?

Comment: You can use ctypes to call `mlockall`, but I think you're prematurely optimizing things here. Have you _tried_ SQLite? It can be surprisingly performant.

Comment: @user1424739 Please see my edit – I added an example server/client thing.